# Can Chrome custom tabs be used in production?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

This [blog](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-chrome-customs-tabs-on-android-ef427effe2f4) here says that users need to have chrome dev to use chrome custom tabs.

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) is also unclear about what happens on devices running below API 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom Tabs is available on Chrome 45, which is already in production. So, the answer is yes, it can be used in production.

When a browser that supports Custom Tabs is not available, the default behaviour is to open the default browser.

Comment: How do I configure the said default behaviour if CustomTabs is not available.

Comment: The solution in this post should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974433/how-can-i-check-whether-chrome-supports-chrome-custom-tabs