# How to check if chrome is not enabled on user's device

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-webview, android-customtabs

I am using `Custom Tabs` to launch `web view`.

The issue is that, if i disable `chrome` it opens the `URL` in an activity, which does not have any button in it.

I want to launch `Web Browser`, if chrome is not installed on your user device, and launch `custom tab`, if chrome is there.

This is my code to launch `Custom Tabs`

```
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                .addDefaultShareMenuItem()
                .setShowTitle(true)
                .build();

// This is optional but recommended
        CustomTabsHelper.addKeepAliveExtra(eContext, customTabsIntent.intent);

// This is where the magic happens...
        CustomTabsHelper.openCustomTab(eContext, customTabsIntent,
                Uri.parse(url),
                new WebViewFallback());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check whether Chrome supports Chrome custom tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974433/how-can-i-check-whether-chrome-supports-chrome-custom-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer how you can check if chrome is disabled.
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("chrome_package_name", 0); boolean isAppEnabled = applicationInfo.enabled;

reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#enabled

Happy to help.